# Proc Export and Proc Import XLSX in WPS/SAS

Tags: sas, wps

I am using WPS (which is essentially writing in SAS) and I am trying to do proc import and proc export of xlsx files but it keeps giving me error. I don't really know which version of SAS I am actually using because the compiler is WPS. Would appreciate any help at all in doing such simple tasks!

For proc import, the codes I used are as such:

```
proc import out=apples replace
   datafile="C:\oranges\apples.xlsx";
   sheet = "fruits";
run;
```

The error I got is:

```
libname _EXCIMP excel "C:\oranges\apples.xlsx" mixed=NO header=YES msengine=ACE use_datetype=YES scan_textsize=YES scan_timety pe=YES   dbmax_text=1024
ERROR: A database error occurred. The database specific error follows:
   DATABASE error: Class not registered;
data apples;
set _EXCIMP.'fruits$'n;run;
          ^
ERROR: Library "_EXCIMP" is not known
```

---

For proc export, the codes I used are as such:

```
PROC EXPORT 
   DATA=have
   DBMS = EXCEL
   LABEL 
OUTFILE='C:\blabla\bla.xlsx' REPLACE;
```

The error I got is:

```
libname _EXCEXP excel 'C:\blabla\bla.xlsx' ms engine=ACE  replace;
ERROR: A database error occurred. The database specific error follows:
   DATABASE error: Class not registered
data _EXCEXP.'have'n;
           ^
ERROR: Library "_EXCEXP" is not known
set have; run;
```

Comment: Try DBMS=Excel2010 FYI- if you pay for WPS license you're also paying for their support.

Comment: @Reeza - you could say the same about SAS

Answer (score 1):

"Class not registered" usually means that you have 64 bit SAS and 32 bit Excel.  Not sure if WPS has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

WPS is different enough that they use different names for their engines.
Try using

```
DBMS=EXCEL2010
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a 64 bits / 32 bits situation.  SAS 64 bits has a free solution for using Office 32 bits. There is no such option with WPS; you must have WPS 32 bits version in order to work with Office 32 bits (still standard and recommended by Microsoft).